# Removing left border of a textbox causes shadow on top and right border

Tags: html, css

I want to merge two textboxes and bring them in line so that they look one. Purpose is to keep the left box disabled with a constant content and the right box editable.

This is my css:

```
.mergeInputLeft
{
    border-right-width: 0;
    float:left;
    background-color : white;
}

 .mergeInputRight
{
    border-left-width: 0;
    outline : none;
}
```

The puspose is served. But these boxes appear slightly different from other boxes on the form as they now have a faint inner shadows on top and right/left borders. And it looks odd. I have checked other similar question, but most the solutions are for removing the borders completely.

Any suggestions!

There is a similar question. However anyone wants to know this is what I did:

```
.mergeInputLeft
{
    border-right-width: 0;
    float:left;
    background-color : white;
    border-style: solid none solid solid;
    border-color:#999;
    border-width:1px;
}

 .mergeInputRight
{
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-style: solid solid solid none;
    border-color:#999;
    border-width:1px;
}
```

Comment: You gave all kinds of border styling for bottom, top and right. Could it have something to do with that?...

Comment: @GolezTrol updated my question and code as per your inputs...the result is same and I still get those shadows on the upper border, which are not seen on the bottom border. It is also visible in your example. If you can have a look.

Comment: It seems you're right. Well, at least I saved you a hell of a lot of CSS then. ;-)  The border seems to be due to styling, as if for a 'full' border, the OS takes care of the styling, while for these modified input boxes, the browser takes over (or vice versa). The effect is likely different too on different browsers and different host systems.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks and yes this is a duplicate!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the borders, for instance by setting the border width to 0. In your case, you apply all kinds of styling to the other borders, which is probably causing the issue. This should be enough:

```css
.a {
  border-right-width: 0;
}
.b {
  border-left-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<input class="a" disabled value="Fixed text"><input class="b">
```